# Plugins to application ( Can i control the namespace/code inside the plugins )

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, interface

Im currently adding a interface to my application so other people can extend it with plugins. My application is used by MMO gamers and i will not have any control over the plugins ( In that anyone will be allowed to make them ) and i was hoping i could have some degree of control over the code in the plugins.

What im afraid of is someone making a plugin that either contains bad code that starts writing to folders outside "allowed" folders or does this by design. Since this will be run by a MMO gamers some sort of keylogger would be very bad.

So im hoping there is a way for me to:
Force the plugin to run inside a sandbox where it does not have direct access to filesystem,windows or network. In effect forcing them to use the API i provide for those actions.
I was thinking it might be posible to inspect the plugin dll hoping it contained a list of what namespaces it uses, and simply not load plugins that contained "bad" namespaces.

My plugin interface is based on [this great codeproject artice](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/pluginsincsharp.aspx) , i did try to search for some information on this. But i was unable to refine my search to a point where it returned something usefull, if it mathers my skill level is C# and some cross platform c++.

Comment: I would check out something like Google's V8 embeddable Javascript engine. It'd require you to use at least some C++, but you could expose whatever interfaces/objects you want instead of having a barn-door-open approach that the plugin architecture you've linked calls for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to inspect the assembly for certain things before you load it.  Prior to executing code or constructing a type within the assembly, you could run through the entire set of assembly types and references using reflection, and search for "invalid" references.  However, this is not going to be very effective, as you're always searching for things that are bad - when really, you need to define the operations that are good, instead, and only allow those.

The only way to cleanly enforce a different security policy for plugin is to load the plugin into a different [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx).

By loading the plugin in it's own AppDomain, you can enforce different security policies upon its code (basically run it within a sand box).  You can provide interfaces or classes that are passed into the plugin in order to give it access to functionality beyond those in the plugin itself.